# simple pipeline runner

Tags: git

I need something that can monitor a Git repository, by polling it at regular intervals. Once new commits are detected, it should pull them and run a specific command or script.

Everything I find seems to be fully-fledged CI/CD platforms with user interfaces, external workers, databases, etc. This is far too complex for the task at hand.

Could someone suggest a basic tool for this purpose?